# Python - tkinter combobox save final values

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I need to append all data that is selected in combobox before it closed as final option (not only unique).
Imagine that you selected '5' in first row and then (while combobox is still open) changed it to '2.4' and then selected '2.4' in all other rows.
Now i have all chosen values in test = ['5', '2.4', '2.4', '2.4', '2.4', '2.4'] but i need only final values in combobox -> test = ['2.4', '2.4', '2.4', '2.4', '2.4']
How to achieve it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tkwindow = tk.Tk()
test = []
selected_values = []

def check_cbox(event):
    selected_values.append(event.widget.get())

def print_c_current_value():
    global selected_values
    if selected_values:
        test.extend(selected_values)
        selected_values = []
    print(test)

for i in range(5):
    cbox = ttk.Combobox(tkwindow, values=['2.4', '5'], state='readonly')
    cbox.grid(column=0, row=i)
    cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", check_cbox)

tk.Button(tkwindow, text="Print C", command=print_c_current_value).grid(column=0, row=5)
tkwindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the selected values of those comboboxes inside `print_c_current_value()` intead of adding selected value into `selected_values` inside `check_box()`.  In order to achieve it, you need to create a list to store those comboboxes.

```py
selected_values = []
cboxes = []  # list to store those comboboxes

def print_c_current_value():
    global selected_values
    selected_values = [cbox.get() for cbox in cboxes]
    print(selected_values)

for i in range(5):
    cbox = ttk.Combobox(tkwindow, values=['2.4', '5'], state='readonly')
    cbox.grid(column=0, row=i)
    cboxes.append(cbox)  # store the combobox
```